# Magento 2 configurable complicated products

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Is there an option that I can make a products as this example:
 - products has 4 size's
 - each size have 4 colors
 - the price depends on the size
 - the quantity depends on the color of the choosen size (meaning each size has it's own quantity depending on the choosen color by the user)

To be more clear maybe the user goes like this:
Choosing his product > choosing size from dropdown > depending on the choosen size he will see the available colors where each of them has it's own quantity and as mentioned before the price will be calculated by the choosen size and that  counts for each size.

Comment: From your post it is clear that the price of the products varies, with the size change of same product in same color but the term, quantity here is little confusing can you please elaborate this a little more?

Comment: ok here is an example of product:
Entrace Mat
size: 122x122(20$), 150x150(25$), 200x200(30$)
color for 122x122(20$): red (quantity25), green(quantity5), black(0)
color for 150x150(25$): red (quantity0), green(25), black(25)
color for 200x200(30$): red (quantity25), green(25), black(25)

So onece the customers chooses "size" he will see the available colors but the price will be calculated depending on the choosen size.

Comment: this feature is already there, you can have the same color with different sizes & prices & as per the selection your price will also update on the front end for the single product (quantity 1) & later if user wants to buy same product multiple quantities the he/she can increase the quantity gradually,
eg.
`color => red; size => 122x122; Qty => 1; price => 20$ || 
color => red; size => 122x122; Qty => 2; price => 40$`

Comment: & you can manage the quantities from back side as per its availabilities in your stock